# How to pass parameters via URL path

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

There are some sites that send parameters via URL like this:

> www.site.com/user/12345678

(just like stackoverflow does)

Can someone give some lectures about the argument? I'd like to learn how this works and implement this into my php platform.

Comment: Start by reading up about [`mod_rewrite`](http://www.google.com/search?q=mod_rewrite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those "pretty urls" are accomplished with the use of **mod_rewrite**.

Any good framework will have this implemented (usually called routes) and in MVC architecture will provide links such as http://www.mysite.com/controller/view/param1/param2...etc.

There are tons of tutorials on the web for "mod rewrite tutorial" such as [this one](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache/).

Comment: Thank you! So i learned that it's not php related. Need to change question tag.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answered: Google keywords `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess`

Example result: http://www.easymodrewrite.com/

Answer (score -1):

This is called "URL Redirection". This is usually done to make URLs user and SEO friendly. You can find the examples/scripts to redirect your URL:

http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/